# makefile: ifeq - what's wrong?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am looking now for a full hour for the problem...
Why is it not `IS 0`?

I am not a big make guru.

```
JAVAC := $(shell javac -version 2> /dev/null; echo $$?) 

all:
    @echo $(JAVAC)
ifeq ($(JAVAC), 0)
    @echo "IS 0"
else
    @echo "NOT 0"
endif
```

Output:

```
#> make
0
NOT 0
```

I'm using GNU Make 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spaces are part of the string being compared. It looks like you have an extra space somewhere, possibly as the last character on the JAVAC:= assignment.

To test this hypothesis, use

```
all:
      @echo '<$(JAVAC)>'
```

Comment: @chris I've edited my answer and suggested a different solution now. I can reproduce your observation by adding a blank in `JAVAC := ...<blank here>`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your comparison like that...

```
ifeq ($(JAVAC), 0)
```

... is like comparing this way:

```
ifeq "$(JAVAC)" " 0"
```

Note the space before the `0`.

---

Simply use the double-quotes notation to avoid any problem, or use [another valid one](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html):

> ```
> ifeq 'arg1' 'arg2'
> ifeq "arg1" "arg2"
> ifeq "arg1" 'arg2'
> ifeq 'arg1' "arg2"
> ```